# Should my form be inside or outside my editor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I am using editor templates in ASP.net MVC. Should I be putting the form inside the editor template or outside of the template?

Example:

**Inside**

~/Views/Products/Create.cshtml

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

~/Views/Products/EditorTemplates/CreateProduct.cshtml

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

**Outside**

~/Views/Products/Create.cshtml

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

~/Views/Products/EditorTemplates/CreateProduct.cshtml

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although neither way is "wrong", I'd definitely say that **outside is better**.

A `form` contributes to the **flow** of your application.  When you try to follow the flow, it usually goes *Controller* > *View*, so putting a `form` into a partial view will do nothing but give you headaches.

In my application, all `form`s are always in the primary view page, so that all editor templates and UI elements are unaware of the "flow" of the application.

Comment: Yeah I was looking more for a "what makes the most amount of sense" answer. Your explanation makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

What suit you best, There is no right and wrong answers to this question.
Non of the framework's HtmlHelper put `<form>` tag while Telerik's Grid control does put `<form>`, so I guess both ways are good.

But I would rather put the `<form>` outside the template, so it can be more flexible, if you put the `<form>` inside the template you might have nested forms which is not supported in any of the browsers.

so I would make a partial view for a `<form>` and an editor template for simple `HtmlHelpers`